# android- how to use ViewModelProviders in custom dialog class

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-viewmodel

I've a custom dialog class , this is my code :

```
class DialogBimegozar_new(act: Activity){
private var dialog: Dialog
private var act: Activity
private lateinit var viewModel:BimeGozarViewModel

init {
    dialog = Dialog(act, R.style.DialogStyler);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_bimegozar_new)

    this.act = act

    makeDialog()

    val lp = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.window?.attributes)
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    dialog.getWindow()?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
    dialog.window?.attributes = lp

    dialog.show()
}

private fun makeDialog() {
    viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(act)

}
```

I want to use my viewmodel in my class , I've an error in this line :

```
viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(act)
```

the error is : 
non of the following option can be called with the argument supplied 
of (Fragment) defined...
of (fragmentActivity) defined....

act in above code is my activity 
what is the problem ? can can I use view model in custom classes ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement you own ViewModelFactory or use sdk provided factory and create instance of your ViewModel. Like:

```
final ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory factory = new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory();
YourViewModel viewModel = factory.create(YourViewModel.class);
```

or if your ViewModel class extends AndroidViewModel:

```
final ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory androidFactory = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(((Application) context.getApplicationContext()));
YourViewModel viewModel = androidFactory.create(YourViewModel.class);
```